# Why are large/pear shaped locking carabiners called HMS carabiners?

Tags: terminology, carabiners, history

Carabiners like this one,

[image: HMS Carabiner]

[Image Source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/Black_Diamond_Airlock_2_HMS_Carabiner.png/640px-Black_Diamond_Airlock_2_HMS_Carabiner.png)

are called HMS carabiners. Why are they called that and what does HMS stand for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These types of carabiners are designed to be used with a [Munter Hitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munter_hitch). The Munter Hitch was created by a Swiss mountain guide named [Werner Munter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_Munter) who called it,

> **Halbmastwurfsicherung**, meaning half clove hitch belay.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munter_hitch)

The abbreviation for **Halbmastwurfsicherung** is HMS and that is why the large/pear shaped carabiners are called HMS carabiners.

Comment: This is a totally correct answer, was it was downvoted because you answered your own question? (Which, to be honest, is answered by the first hit from google...)

Comment: @Guran There is now way to be sure, but that could be. Give it 48 hours and this will be the top the Google result.

Comment: There isnt anything wrong with answering your own question if you did the legwork to find the information out yourself.

Comment: @Zissouu You're right about answering your own question. According to the help center page [Can I answer my own question?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), it's not only allowed, but encouraged. The downvote could have been for that, or anything else, but I figured I'd document what the Help Center says since it was brought up here. You can also accept your own answer, but you have two wait 48 hours, which is fair in case someone comes by and doesn't want to add an answer because one is already accepted.